# Time frequency analysis for a spreading signal

Tags: digital-communications

I am a beginner in digital communications: I am studying the spread spectrum communication and I have a question on the spreading signals. For example I have 2 spreading signals and I do a time frequency analysis.

Should the spreading signals overlap in time? And if yes, why?

Comment: What do you know about spread spectrum?

Answer (score 0):

The overlap is not important, it is just necessary that the spreading sequences  are pseudo-orthogonal.

Can someone confirm?

Comment: Are you the same user who asked the original question? Spread spectrum can be used as a multiple access scheme to separate the signals in the code domain. So, the different signals can overlap in time and frequency, as long as they can be separated in the code domain using orthogonal or quasi-orthogonal spreading sequence codes.